# format HTML string that is obtained from json android

Tags: android, html, textview

I am getting an `HTML` string from the `json` data . I want to normalize the string, so that I can use it in `Textview`

```
"ProductDetails":"
\\r\\n\\tDINE COLLECTION
\\r\\n\\tDNCH06 - Silver
\\r\\n\\t16”W X 17”D X 38.5”H   Blueprint
\\r\\n\\tStudios Exclusive. Patented Design.<\\\/p>\\r\\n

\\r\\n\\t <\\\/p>\\r\\n

\\r\\n\\t <\\\/p>\\r\\n"
```

I used

```
product_details=product_details.replaceAll("(\\r\\n|\\n\r|\\r|\\n)", "<br />");     
txt_prod_det.setText(Html.fromHtml(product_details));
```

but didn't worked :(

Comment: Please show the html string first. And show the result of replaceAll. And tell 'what did not worked'. What happened instead?

Comment: You probably showed already what you consider a html string. You should first unescape it by replacing "\\" by "\". Do that twice. Finally use Html.fromHtml().